# Send values from file with link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm here to ask you things about Google Sheets macro,
I want to send information from Google Sheet file to another.
I wanted, when I click on the link, that it takes and send the values from the same row to the other

file[image].

Comment: Welcome. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: About `when I click on the link, that it takes and send the values from the same row to the other file`, I cannot understand about `link` you expect. For example, you are thinking about Web Apps or others? I thought that to use the checkbox as the switch for running the script might be suitable for your situation. How about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just paste into code.gs and run showSideBar function.  Pay attention to the instructions provided in the top of the sidebar and everything should work just fine.

```
function sendCurrentRow() {
  var tssid='target spreadsheet id';//put the target spreadsheet id here
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  const row=sh.getRange(rg.getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(tssid);
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName(sh.getName());
  if(!tsh) {
    var tsh=tss.insertSheet(sh.getName())
  }
  tsh.getRange(rg.getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(row);  
}

function showSideBar() {
  var html='<p>If you haven put you target spreadsheet id in function sendCurrentRow() then do before pressing button below.</p><p>Place cursor on the row you wish to send and click button below.</p><br />'
  html+='<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="google.script.run.sendCurrentRow()" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Send Current Row'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it ! :D